# Combining Multiple Smart Chips to 1 cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to concatenate multiple Smart Chips to 1 cell per team using a formula. I have tried using textjoin, index match, vlookup but for some reason I am not able to make it work since the formula will return as email instead of Smart Chip. Is it even possible to combine multiple smart chips into 1 single cell?

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nj661WVJIljo56FkDRGV6tXSne_lFNpZjqto4Xc2PuI/edit#gid=0).

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

If you want one cell to feature multiple people, [it's not possible](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/174028356?hl=en&msgid=174048114).